# Get values of related models from form in template (not so much hidden filed)

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

i have UpdateView opening form,

```
url(r'^calendar/(?P<pk>[0-9]*)/update/$',  UpdateView.as_view(model=Calendar,success_url='..',template_name_suffix='_update_form'),name='calendar_update'),
```

where one of fileds point to really long list via ForeignKey :

```
class Calendar(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task,help_text=u"Task")
    ...
class Task(models.Model):
    long_name = models.TextField(blank=True,help_text=u"")
    ...
```

which is not going to change in the form, so i want it have in the template as a hidden field (no problem so far) but also I would like to have shown its value there (but not have to get the full table, as Select list do).

I would like have it something like this:

```
...
<tr><td>{{ form.task.label_tag}}</td>
<td>{{ form.task.as_hidden }} {{ form.task.long_name }}</td></tr>
```

where long_name is field on the Task related record (TextField), but it does not work

Is there a way to get the related name without having to get the data manually and manage everything with that form in views.py?

Comment: Please show your view.

Comment: None view is involved, as I am usind the UpdateView, which does everything itself. And I would like to avoid writing view just for this. [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView)